# Networking in Google Cloud Platform, where to look for holistic information - Unknown host

Tags: google-cloud-platform

1. I have a Kubernetes Cluster going "Unknown host"
2. Then I need to learn more bout networks, pools, firewalls, loadbalancer etc. to be able to solve this.

Question: Where do I look for more holistic information - I need the information that describe the connections between the network settings?

Comment: An unknown host is an error message that generates when a destination host server name cannot be resolved probably due to either the user's provided host server name does not exist or match any Domain Name System (DNS) records.

I would like to know your total setup and step by step instructions for how you have reached the issue (steps are taken to determine/before observing the potential issue).

Comment: I am sharing this article[1] which provides an overview of the main aspects of Google Kubernetes Engine networking.[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview